# How to prevent negative values from JSON file (java)

Tags: java, json, parsing, console, console-application

I'm trying to create java console application that generates some reports and I make some verifications if the values in json data file are negative and I don't want to be negative(for example: Employee name cannot be null)

I tried to set the value in Setter, because the name field is private. Then I started the application with negative value in json file that i take data from it, and it doesn't throw the exception and the message that I was declared

```
public void setName(String name) {
    if (name == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The Employee's name cannot be null.");
    }

    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: The negative value(for name) in json file is null or empty string ??

Comment: when it is empty string it outputs nothing, and when it is null, it outputs null, but for the both cases it doesn't throw exception

Comment: Hi Alex, Welcome to StackOverflow! I am assuming by negative you mean "unacceptable" values for an attribute. could you post the code snippet where you are calling the setter?

Comment: Then change your if condition such that it satisfies both null and empty string. Hint: you can use name.length()==0

Comment: thank you,@arjithn

I'm not calling a setter, because I use the value from my json file
this is a part from my data.json

{
"name": "John Wick",
"totalSales": 250
...
}

Comment: @Nitika I'm sorry if my questions are dumb, but when i try this one name.length()==0 it writes Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'int', 'null'

Comment: because length() is only for String not int

Comment: @Nitika but i have been declared name as String, why it gives me that problem

Comment: Can you please post your json which contains negative values / for which your code is failing now ?

Comment: @Nitika 
{
"name": " ",
"totalSales": -250
}
this example must print this messages -"The Employee's name cannot be null." and "Employee total sales must be a positive number." (without quotes)

I have another properties and I have the same problem with negative values

Comment: @AlexDr then apply condition for totalSales too. Hint: totalSales < 0

Comment: @AlexDr in your case- exception is thrown in the first iteration,so flow execution is stopped.

Comment: @AlexDr I tried sysout in place of throw new IllegalArgumentException and it worked fine.

Comment: @AlexDr See my answer with respect to your github code link which is now deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your Employee Constructor to this: to catch all exceptions.

```java
public Employee(String name, int totalSales, int salesPeriod, double experienceMultiplier) {
        try {
            this.setName(name);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            this.setTotalSales(totalSales);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            this.setSalesPeriod(salesPeriod);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            this.setExperienceMultiplier(experienceMultiplier);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the name parameter passed in the method is not null.

```
public void setName(String name) {
    if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The Employee's name cannot be null.");
    }

    this.name = name;
}
```

Add conditions to the **if** statement that has to be thrown as Exception.